# Want to keep JDKs together in one place on a macbook

Tags: java, macos, directory-structure

On a Macbook with Yosemite, I have Java JDKs 1.6 and 1.8 in the following directories respectively:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

I'm also pretty sure I have 1.7 somewhere but can't find it right now (if not I'm probably going to get it). Anyhow I was thinking et'd be a good idea to keep them all together, so where do you think I should put them? Why? Does it matter as long as the software I'm using (e.g. Eclipse) knows where they are?

Thanks, Niall

Comment: What'd that be good for? When you move system files like this, make sure to update all path settings everywhere to match the new location, or you'll break stuff

Comment: @MightyPork: What'd that be good for? Well, (I think) e.g. if I install 3rd-party libraries I don't want them duplicated all over the place. But honestly I'm in over my head and don't really know anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

up to version 6 Java was provided by Apple and was installed in */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*. Since version 7 Java is provided by Oracle and is installed in */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/* when using the .dmg installer.

I would advise against moving the old installation of version 6 to a different places, there used to be a couple of symlinks pointing to that installation.

From 7 on, they reside side by side in the given directory, and so are in one place. For example this is the content of my /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102  7 Aug 10:21 jdk1.7.0_67.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 15 Okt 10:46 jdk1.7.0_71.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 28 Apr  2014 jdk1.8.0_05.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 16 Jul 10:32 jdk1.8.0_11.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102  4 Sep 12:34 jdk1.8.0_20.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 15 Okt 10:47 jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
```

If you need to point your JAVA_HOME environment variable automatically to the actual version, you can put the following command in your .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

In your IDE, Eclipse or IDEA, set the path to the installation directory to the needed JDK by defining a JDK or JRE pointing to the directory with the needed version. I myself didn't even reinstall Java 6 after updating to yosemite, so my installations are all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you can launch Eclipse, you can use the default Java in your own programs inside Eclipse without any further work.

The tricky part come if you need to use another JVM with your own programs than the one used by Eclipse itself.  I would consider that something only very advanced users need to be able to handle.

Moving installed files around is generally a bad idea unless you *really*, *really* know what you are doing.  I would advise against it.